# Is it possible to run a server on a mounted file system?

Tags: unix, mount

I have two machines testserver and dev. I have the /opt directry on testserver mounted on my dev machine. Both machines are unix.

I need to create and run an OpenDJ ldap server in the mounted directory, Is this possible?

Here is the output :

```
 [exec] OpenDJ 2.5.0-Xpress1
 [exec] Please wait while the setup program initializes...
 [exec] ERROR:  Unable to bind to port 2901.  This port may already be in use, or you
 [exec] may not have permission to bind to it
 [exec] ERROR:  Unable to bind to port 9444.  This port may already be in use, or you
 [exec] may not have permission to bind to it
 [exec] Result: 2
```

The port is definitely not in use.

**Edit**
I have given the mounted directory the following permissions :

```
chown nobody:nogroup /opt
```

Should I create a user nobody on the dev machine? I have limited experience with mounted systems and how permissions work so I'm unsure.

**Edit 2**
Upon re-reading the question, I don't think its clear that I had hoped that the server would run on the testserver machine, **not** the dev machine

Comment: Had you try to run the same OpenDJ from another directory on `dev` ? (just to see if the problem is FS location dependent)

Comment: no good idea..I'll try that now

Comment: ah I ran it again and instead of the server running on testserver:9444, it rajn on dev:9444. I should have read up a bit more on mounted filesystems before I started this task. I thought it would run on testserver:9444

Comment: So what you actually need is to remotely run the server on `testserver` from the `dev` machine?

Comment: yes..I'm building a system with several components on different machines. I'm using ant to build and set up these components and thought it would be nice to be able to do it from the one location without using scp to copy and ssh to log in

Comment: For anyone who might be trying to do something similar, I ended up just using sshexec to run commands on the remote machine through ant

Comment: You can write this as an answer, so it would be easer for people to find it. I would have add something about the original need and a summary of what worked and what didn't.